# MySQL Select Multiple latest Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with user stats and need to select only the latest values for each user:

Im using php timestamp to enter the date/lastlogin.

**stat_id:** auto increment

**stat_user:** The user that logged in

**stat_count:** The amount of times he logged in

**stat_lastlogin:** The last time he logged in

**table: user_stats**

```
stat_id       | stat_user   | stat_count | stat_lastlogin
---------------------------------------------------------
1             | Admin       |      1     | 1386661327
2             | User        |      1     | 1386661340
3             | Guest       |      1     | 1386661358
4             | Admin       |      2     | 1386662383
5             | Guest       |      2     | 1386663794
6             | Admin       |      3     | 1386663806
7             | Super       |      1     | 1386663812
```

So what i want to achieve is the following when displaying the output:

```
stat_id       | stat_user   | stat_count | stat_lastlogin
---------------------------------------------------------
2             | User        |      1     | 1386661340
5             | Guest       |      2     | 1386663794
6             | Admin       |      3     | 1386663806
7             | Super       |      1     | 1386663812
```

There can be an unlimited amount of users.

Eventually i would like to have the stats show logins per month for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leveraging MySQL non-standard `GROUP BY` extension you can do

```sql
SELECT stat_id, stat_user, stat_count, stat_lastlogin
  FROM 
(
  SELECT stat_id, stat_user, stat_count, stat_lastlogin 
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY stat_lastlogin DESC
) q
 GROUP BY stat_user
```

or in a more standard way

```sql
SELECT t.stat_id, t.stat_user, t.stat_count, t.stat_lastlogin
  FROM 
(
  SELECT stat_user, MAX(stat_lastlogin) stat_lastlogin
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY stat_user
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.stat_user = t.stat_user
   AND q.stat_lastlogin = t.stat_lastlogin
 ORDER BY stat_user
```

or if `stat_lastlogin` is not being updated (meaning the higher `stat_id` the more recent record is)

```sql
SELECT t.stat_id, t.stat_user, t.stat_count, t.stat_lastlogin
  FROM 
(
  SELECT MAX(stat_id) stat_id
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY stat_user
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.stat_id = t.stat_id
 ORDER BY stat_user
```

Output:

```
| STAT_ID | STAT_USER | STAT_COUNT | STAT_LASTLOGIN |
|---------|-----------|------------|----------------|
|       6 |     Admin |          3 |     1386663806 |
|       5 |     Guest |          2 |     1386663794 |
|       7 |     Super |          1 |     1386663812 |
|       2 |      User |          1 |     1386661340 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d396e/10)** demo for all queries

Comment: Your first way works perfect, when the user logs in a new record will be added with an updated date each time which in turn will then add +1 to the stat_count, so the latest login will always have the most recent information. The only reason i used this layout is because i will have to show how many times per month for each year a user has logged in at a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

could you try this?

```
SELECT user_stat.*
FROM user_stat INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT stat_user, MAX(stat_lastlogin) as ll
    FROM user_stats
    GROUP BY stat_user
) x ON user_stat.stat_user = x.stat_user AND user_stat.stat_lastlogin = x.ll
```